# Excel - formula link cells based on another column

Tags: excel

I want to use a formula (or a function I'll make in VBA, I prefer a formula) to do the following:
I have text in column A, that I want to link in Column E based on similar cells in column B.
For example: cell B2,B3,B4 equals "A" and I want cell E2 to be the values in column A with a ";" between the values.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula for this:
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(B:B=B2,A:A,""))

Enter the formula in the bar in cell E2 and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to create an array formula.

Comment: TEXTJOIN will work only in the latest versions of excel

Comment: I did what you told me, and i'm getting "Apple;Banana;Orange" across all of E2:E6

Comment: Did you press ctrl+shift+enter and drag it down? Make sure that cell in the B:B=B2 there are no $ symbols. For example in cell E6 it should look like `{=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(B:B=B6,A:A,""))}`

Comment: Works now. perfect !

Comment: Good to hear, array formulas are very underutilised imo. Please remember to mark a best answer if your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it using a formula but below VBA method will work.

1. Press Alt + F11 in the worksheet to open the VBA editor window
2. In the left pane, Right click sheet1 and Insert module
3. Copy paste the below method
4. Use the method MultipleLookupNoRept in the formula

   Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, 
   ColumnNumber As Integer)
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Result As String
   For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
   If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
   For J = 1 To i - 1
   If LookupRange.Cells(J, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
   If LookupRange.Cells(J, ColumnNumber) = LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) 
   Then
   GoTo Skip
   End If
   End If
   Next J
   Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ";"
   Skip:
   End If
   Next i
   MultipleLookupNoRept = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
   End Function

   [image]

[image]